# $uid not picking up the value

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parameter-passing

I am trying to download Facebook profile picture for Facebook application. For this, I'm getting the value of Facebook username/id in `$uid`. `echo $uid` is showing the correct result but it's not picking up the value when I use it in the following code:

```
echo $uid;
$imgDestinationPath = 'pic.jpg';
$link = 'http://graph.facebook.com/$uid/picture?type=large';
$content = file_get_contents($link);
file_put_contents($imgDestinationPath, $content);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Moreover, when I put the Facebook username instead of `$uid`, it downloads the picture then.
Please help. I'm new to PHP.

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL); to the start of the code and look for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use the " " in this statement

```
$link = "http://graph.facebook.com/$uid/picture?type=large";
```

will solve the problem

Comment: thanks for the help.. i have one more problem as well. pls see to it [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633912/download-help-facebook-app)

Answer (score 1):

$uid does not get evaluated, try this instead:

```
$link = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/picture?type=large';
```

or you can do it with a double quote:

```
$link = "http://graph.facebook.com/$uid/picture?type=large";
```

I would prefer the first solution. This makes the code more readable to me.

Comment: thanks for the help.. i have one more problem as well. pls see to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633912/download-help-facebook-app